# How can I do this with Vue js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
data: [
  {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'online'},
  {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'online'},
  {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'offline'},
  {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'online'},
  {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'offline'},
  {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'online'},
  {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'offline'},
]
```

I have data similar to this and I need to get the number of online users here and print it on the screen vue js how can I do it? I found it a long way but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find all the array entries that have `status: 'online'`, then return the length of that array:

```js
const onlineUsers = data.filter(x => x.status === 'online')
const onlineCount = onlineUsers.length
```

To show that count in a Vue template, you could compute the result above and use string interpolation syntax (prop name between `{{` and `}}`):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data: [
        {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'online'},
        {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'online'},
        {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'offline'},
        {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'online'},
        {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'offline'},
        {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'online'},
        {name: 'xxxxx', surname: 'yyyyy', status: 'offline'},
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    onlineCount() {
      return this.data.filter(x => x.status === 'online').length;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>{{onlineCount}} users are online</div>
</div>
```